# View is not rendering in Backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js, rendering, backbone-views

I'm trying to render a search box on my page. I'm trying to keep it in a seperate view. The page without this boxview is working correctly but as soon as i initialize my BoxView  i get the error related to underscore.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'replace' underscore-min.js:29
```

Here is my View

```
/* Views */

var BoxView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '.head',
    initialize: function() {
        this.render();
    },
    render : function(){
        var that = this;
        var template = _.template($('#search-box').html());
        that.$el.html(template);
    }
});

  var boxview = new BoxView();
```

Template

```
<script type="text/template" id="search-box">
<form class="navbar-search pull-right" id="search">
<input class="search-query" name="searchText" type="text" id="searchText" placeholder="Search books"/>
<button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
</form>
</script>
```

EDIT : 
Removed the typo error

Comment: possible duplicate of [Underscore.js Template Issue - Cannot call method 'replace' of null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11001419/underscore-js-template-issue-cannot-call-method-replace-of-null)

Comment: You're calling `_.template(null)` somewhere, check what's in `$('#search-box')` before you `_.template($('#search-box').html())`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me it's just a typo:

```
var template = _.template($('#search-box')).html();
```

should be:

```
var template = _.template($('#search-box').html());
```

**Edit:**
I'd normally assume this is the kind of typo made while writing the question, but your error suggests the problem comes from an underscore call (you only have one), and that it's trying to use `replace` on an object. `_.template` surely uses `replace` and you give it an object (`$('#search-box')`). So it makes sense.

Comment: @Abhishek Are you sure you don't have the typo in your code too? http://jsfiddle.net/5bYHF/ that works fine.

Comment: Yes there is no typo in code. There are two views actually. With both of them in place I'm getting error. Once I remove this, it works fine

Comment: @Abhishek what you posted contains no error, post more code else I'm afraid I can't help you.